# how to replace domain name in file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

We want to replace any domain name with old domain name that exists in **dn.txt** file

example:

```
domainName=`  hostname | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $2}' `
echo $domainName
trump1
```

so in this case trump1 will replace the old domain name - obbama

note - variable $domainName could be any **other domain name** , the command should replace variable value with old domain name in **dn.txt** file

example - before:

```
more dn.txt
hive-site,hive.zookeeper.quorum,master01.obbama.com:2181,master02.obbama.com:2181,master03.obbama.com:2181

site,hive.zookeeper.quorum,worker01.obbama.com:2181,worker02.obbama.com:2181,worker03.obbama.com:2181

.
.
```

example - after - expected output

```
hive-site,hive.zookeeper.quorum,master01.trump1.com:2181,master02.trump1.com:2181,master03.trump1.com:2181

site,hive.zookeeper.quorum,worker01.trump1.com:2181,worker02.trump1.com:2181,worker03.trump1.com:2181
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`sed`** approach:

```
domainName="trump"
sed -Ee "s/[^.]+(\.com:)/${domainName}\1/g" dn.txt
```

The output:

```
hive-site,hive.zookeeper.quorum,master01.trump.com:2181,master02.trump.com:2181,master03.trump.com:2181

site,hive.zookeeper.quorum,worker01.trump.com:2181,worker02.trump.com:2181,worker03.trump.com:2181
```

Comment: better to add -i   as sed -Eie "s/[^.]+(\.com:)/${domainName}\1/g"